# I have four logo graphic image that I want to put in four different pages of my title slide. beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I am trying to put four images in one title slide at four different places and not in one single line.

Comment: Look for "tikz absolute positioning picture" and maybe clarify your question and and a so-called minimal working example.

Comment: *"and and" --> "and add" (MWE --> https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228)

Answer (score 1):

I could do it by using `\logo{}` command two times as below: I have used empty `\logo{}` command the second time so that the output give logos only on the title page.

```
\logo{\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.9\textwidth}

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{ubfc}\vspace{10mm}\\
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{p2food}
\column{.8\textwidth}

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{agrosup}\vspace{10mm}\\
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{nutox}
\end{columns}}
\maketitle
\logo{}
\begin{frame}{Contents}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```